# Javascript random number between 0 and 1

Tags: javascript, random, floating-point

I can't seem to generate a **random float** number from **0.0** to **1.0** with `Math.floor((Math.random() * 1.0) + 0.0);`

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: `Math.floor()` probably turns *any* value in the range `[0.0, 1.0>` into 0.0. Get rid of the `Math.floor()` call. What are `* 1.0` and `+ 0.0` supposed to do? Just use plain `Math.random()` and get rid of the rest.

Comment: Maybe `Math.round(Math.random())`? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) as is will generate a random float number between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Working example:

```js
document.getElementById("generate").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("random").value = Math.random();
};
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate random number</button>
<input id="random">
```

Comment: From 0 inclusive to 1 exclusive. So it will never return 1.

Comment: @dusky Correct. `Math.random()` always generates numbers for range `[0, 1)`. The min-max solution proposed by the OP works in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably see, multiplying by 1.0 and adding 0.0 is completely useless. What breaks your mechanism is the Math.floor, which most likely reduces your number to 0.0, regardless of what number between 0.0 and 1.0 Math.random returns.